# aws assume role on shell script does not assume the role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm following a tutorial where I assume roles on EC2 instances so it has access to services. I'm following this tutorial (https://medium.com/swlh/aws-iam-assuming-an-iam-role-from-an-ec2-instance-882081386c49), but I'm stuck on the cli part when I start running a "aws s3 ls". Just so I know it works, I gave the AssumedRole all access to s3.

This is my setup:

```
ImplicitRole // will be attached to EC2
   policy: 
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/*"
        }
    ]
}

AssumedRole // will be the role assumed once logged in to EC2
  policy:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What happens is I would run the following on cli

```
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::****:role/AssumedRole --role-session-name test-session
```

Then I will get the Credentials

```
{
    "Credentials": {
        "AccessKeyId": "key",
        "SecretAccessKey": "secret",
        "SessionToken": "longtoken",
        "Expiration": "2020-07-08T07:29:51+00:00"
    },
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "AKDIEEOOKDLKSDJFDJ:test-session",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::xxxx:assumed-role/AssumedRole/test-session"
    }
}
```

and then will update the variables eg: set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXX , etc

Once done I run the following but it would give me ListObject AccessDenied

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucket

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied
```

Comment: Where do you set `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXX`? You should export them: `export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXX` as well as the access key and token before cli can pick it up.

Comment: Try `aws sts get-caller-identity` to ensure you're calling the API using the role's credentials.

Comment: @Marcin , i set them right after I do the sts assume. I'm trying it out line by line on cli to see how it works.

Comment: @DennisTraub, I tried it out, it's showing me the ImplicitRole instead of the AssumedRole